# Updating Status when there is a duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

How can I update my status to 1 if the condition is same Reference, but 1 reference should be Debit and 1 credit.  If they are 3 records with same Reference but 2 with same debit amount and 1 credit 2 records should be updated to 1 that is 1 with credit and 1 with Debit using SQL

Comment: Although this is clearly excel.. I suggest you ask this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A little punctuation will make the question a lot clearer.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. the explanation is not very clear. Please post your table schema, sample data in DML format and expected result as text. Also include your current attempt query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to identify lines where debit is same as credit

The `row_number()` inside the `cte` is to generate a sequence number for matching `Debit` with `Credit`.

The matching is handle at `sum() over ()` expression `partition by Reference, coalesce(Debit, Credit), r`

```
with trans as
(
    select  Reference, Debit, Credit,
            r = row_number() over (partition by Reference, Debit, Credit
                    order by Debit, Credit)     
    from    tbl 
)
select  *,
        case when sum ( isnull(Debit, 0) - isnull(Credit, 0) ) 
                 over ( partition by Reference, coalesce(Debit, Credit), r ) = 0
             then 1
             else 0 
             end
from    trans;
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abfa3ef827f2ab28cbd54d73e3692ba1)

Comment: The query works. If they are 3 it will select  and mark the left 1 as 0. Thanks